# Brace expansion seemingly not working in Bash 3.2.51 on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash

I have a bunch of LaTeX files on my Desktop:

```
ma 512 hw 11.log, ma 512 hw 11.aux, ma 512 hw 11.tex
```

etc.

I want to use brace expansion to print them to the Terminal. E.g.,

```
ls *.{log, aux}
```

But when I try to give this command, I get the following errors:

```
ls: *.{aux,: No such file or directory
ls: log}: No such file or directory
```

So clearly it's not doing the brace expansion. What am I missing?

[image]

[I'm using Bash 3.2.51 on OS X 10.9.2]

EDIT: I thought it might be a problem with the fact that the files have spaces in their names, but when I tried it again with a no-space name, the same thing happened (see image).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured out the problem. You can't put spaces between `aux` and `log` because bash splits on spaces. (Duh!)

This works:

`ls *.{aux,log}`

[image]